# installing C++ library with homebrew

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install a C++ library (**gtkmm**) for my project and to test this installation with a simple test file (the main from wikipedia page about gtkmm).
I did `brew install gtkmm3`, it installed it but when I compile with `clang++ -Wall -Werror -Wextra -o test test.cpp` it doesn't find my header :

```
test.cpp:15:10: fatal error: 'gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h' file not found
#include <gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h>
```

The header is located at `~/homebrew/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h`.
I tried :

- adding `$HOME"/homebrew/include"` to `$PATH` and using `#include <gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h>` in my source file.
- adding `$HOME"/homebrew/include/gtkmm-3.0"` to my `$PATH` and using `#include <gtkmm.h>` in my source file.

But I still can't compile.

How could I do?

Comment: `$PATH` is not used by the compiler to find header files, it is used by the shell to find programs you try to run. Instead, use the `-I </path/to/headers>` option of the compiler. You will likely also need to use `-L` to provide the path to the library, and `-l` to tell it to link that library.

Comment: That's true, now it finds it. But the header it now finds requires itself an other header that isn't found. (the dependency is installed though), do I have to add -I and -L to manually add each dependency? Isn't there a way by modifying environment variables to install libraries with brew to compile without adding these options?

Comment: When you installed did anything mention that they were `keg-only`. This means they were installed but not placed in the standard location (because there is a issue with doing that automatically). Because they are not in the standard location the compiler can not find them. Either you have to manually indicate the location or Look up `brew link --force`

Comment: @LokiAstari There was nothing when I installed it. I'll check out `brew link --force`.

Comment: I just tried and it installed it here: `ls /usr/local/include/gdkmm-3.0/gdkmm.h`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use `pkgconfig` like this and it will tell you all the include paths and the link paths you need:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags /usr/local/Cellar/gtkmm3/*/lib/pkgconfig/gdkmm-3.0.pc
```

**Output**

```
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/gtkmm3/3.18.0/include/gdkmm-3.0 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/gtkmm3/3.18.0/lib/gdkmm-3.0/include 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/glibmm/2.46.3/include/giomm-2.4 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/glibmm/2.46.3/lib/giomm-2.4/include 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/pangomm/2.38.1/include/pangomm-1.4 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/pangomm/2.38.1/lib/pangomm-1.4/include 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/glibmm/2.46.3/include/glibmm-2.4 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/glibmm/2.46.3/lib/glibmm-2.4/include 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.18.6/include/gtk-3.0 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/include/gio-unix-2.0/ 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6/include/cairo  
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libepoxy/1.3.1/include 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.38.1/include/pango-1.0 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/1.1.3/include/harfbuzz 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.38.1/include/pango-1.0 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/atk/2.18.0/include/atk-1.0 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6/include/cairo 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/cairomm/1.12.0/include/cairomm-1.0 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/cairomm/1.12.0/lib/cairomm-1.0/include 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6/include/cairo 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.32.8/include/pixman-1 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1/include 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/include/freetype2 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.20/include/libpng16 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libsigc++/2.6.2/include/sigc++-2.0 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libsigc++/2.6.2/lib/sigc++-2.0/include 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.32.3/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.20/include/libpng16 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/include/glib-2.0 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib/glib-2.0/include 
-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gtkmm3/3.18.0/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/glibmm/2.46.3/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/pangomm/2.38.1/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/glibmm/2.46.3/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.18.6/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.38.1/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/atk/2.18.0/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/cairomm/1.12.0/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/libsigc++/2.6.2/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.32.3/lib 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib 
-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib 
-lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lglibmm-2.4 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lgio-2.0 -lcairomm-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Then you can compile with:

```
clang++ $(pkg-config --libs --cflags /usr/local/Cellar/gtkmm3/*/lib/pkgconfig/gdkmm-3.0.pc) someFile.cpp -o someFile
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you! :) I just had to add c++11 flag though.